# Create an summarizing variable for multiple columns in data.table r

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have the following `data.table`

```
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4),
                 date=c("2019-09-13", "2018-12-06", "2017-12-14", "2018-02-08", "2015-12-06", "2012-12-14", "2011-02-08"),
                 variable_1=c("a","b",NA,NA,"b","c",NA),
                 variable_2=c(NA,NA,"a",NA,"a","c",NA),
                 variable_3=c(NA,NA,NA,"b","c","c",NA))
dt
id       date variable_1 variable_2 variable_3
1:  1 2019-09-13          a       <NA>       <NA>
2:  2 2018-12-06          b       <NA>       <NA>
3:  2 2017-12-14       <NA>          a       <NA>
4:  2 2018-02-08       <NA>       <NA>          b
5:  3 2015-12-06          b          a          c
6:  3 2012-12-14          c          c          c
7:  4 2011-02-08       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

I want to create a variable `y` that is summarizing all the columns. Everything that has one `!is.na()` among the variable should be `0` . Every row that has only `is.na` among all the variables should be `1`. Like this:

```
   id       date variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 y
1:  1 2019-09-13          a       <NA>       <NA> 0
2:  2 2018-12-06          b       <NA>       <NA> 0
3:  2 2017-12-14       <NA>          a       <NA> 0
4:  2 2018-02-08       <NA>       <NA>          b 0
5:  3 2015-12-06          b          a          c 0
6:  3 2012-12-14          c          c          c 0
7:  4 2011-02-08       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 1
```

In the original `data.table` I have 22 variables that I am looking at among 830 total variables. So I would prefer not to look for every Variable with `_1` to `_22` separately.
Is there a way in `data.table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
dt[, y := +(rowSums(!is.na(.SD)) == 0L), .SDcols = patterns("^variable_")]
#    id       date variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 y
# 1:  1 2019-09-13          a       <NA>       <NA> 0
# 2:  2 2018-12-06          b       <NA>       <NA> 0
# 3:  2 2017-12-14       <NA>          a       <NA> 0
# 4:  2 2018-02-08       <NA>       <NA>          b 0
# 5:  3 2015-12-06          b          a          c 0
# 6:  3 2012-12-14          c          c          c 0
# 7:  4 2011-02-08       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 1
```

Walk-through:

- `.SDcols=patterns(...)` defines the columns to be processed as `.SD` in the `j` component. This doesn't involve *removing*/*selecting* columns for the output, just the ones that will be referenced internally.
- `!is.na(.SD)` returns a `logical` `matrix`, same dims as `.SD`, indicating if its value is `NA`.
- `rowSums(...)` returns the count of non-`NA`s in the row.
- using the inverted logic of "count the number of *non*-`NA` values in a row", we're able to not care about the number of columns being processed; this is what allows me to use `== 0L`.
- `+(...)` is a shorthand trick for converting `logical` to `0:1`

Comment: +1 and great explanation! If you like two unary operators next to each other, here is some code golf fun: ```dt[, z := +!rowSums(!is.na(.SD)), .SDcols = patterns("^variable_")]```. At the very least, it works on this dataset.